# Ruby - set instance variable inside class method from string

Tags: ruby, class, setter, instance-variables

I have a class with a method `register(key, val)`. I am trying to add `key` as a instance variable of the class and set it equal to `val`. Right now I'm trying to use `self.instance_variable_set(':@' + key, val)` but I'm getting this error:

```
in `instance_variable_set': `:@table' is not allowed as an instance variable name (NameError)
```

I am calling `register('table',  {'key' => 'value'})`

Any idea how to do this properly? Thanks!

Comment: @DaveNewton that is a confusing statement.

Comment: @DaveNewton *"it's not a class method if you're referencing `self`"* this makes very little sense to me. `self` can reference a `Class` just as it can reference an instance of a `Class` and if we are being technical about this all methods are `instance_methods` because everything is an instance.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: is the error message really that hard to understand? Can you give any hints as to how it could be improved for future readers?

Comment: I'm really new to Ruby, so I didn't know what the solution was. In hindsight, the error message made perfect sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `:` from your method.

`self.instance_variable_set('@' + key, val)`

Moreover, `self` can be redundant here. Try `instance_variable_set('@' + key, val)`.

And prefer to use interpolation over concatenation. `instance_variable_set("@#{key}", val)`

Comment: I tried the interpolation method and it works with double quotes but not single quotes, do you know why that is?

Comment: @achang27 it's because, well ... string interpolation works within double quotes but not within single quotes. That's the way [string literals](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings) work in Ruby.

Comment: Regarding `:` – if you want to pass the instance variable's name as a symbol (as shown in the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set)), the [syntax](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Symbols) is `:"@#{key}"`. With `key = 'table'`, it returns the symbol `:@table`